# How to use treeview in Sharepoint 2010 Sandbox solution?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution

I have tried using Treeview in my Sanboxsolution webpart but the problem is that in a web page it is not loading properly. And when i click on node it gives me javascript error. For these two errors i have attached screenshots with this question for the reference.Have a look at it.

And in my aspx view i have written following code

```
<asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="trvComDept" ShowLines="True" ShowExpandCollapse="true" EnableClientScript="true" ImageSet="Simple">
<Nodes>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Parent 1" Value="1">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Child 1" Value="2"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Child 2" Value="3"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
</Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Webpage View
[image]

JS Error when i click on node
[image]

**Updated Code Is As Below**

Aspx Code :-

```
<asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="trvComDept" ShowLines="True" ShowExpandCollapse="true" EnableClientScript="true" ImageSet="Simple">
```

C# Code :

```
List<string> Roots = new List<string>();
        List<string> Childs = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Roots.Add("Root" + i.ToString());
            Childs.Add("Child" + i.ToString());
        }

        foreach (string r in Roots)
        {
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
            root.Text = r;

            foreach (string c in Childs)
            {
                TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
                child.Text = c;
                root.ChildNodes.Add(child);
            }

            trvComDept.Nodes.Add(root);
        }
```

Comment: Does this work WITHOUT the C# code? If so, I would get rid of the Nodes section in your aspx markup, and see if the C# then again works.

Comment: I have to bind the Treeview from the SPList so i must need c# code

Comment: Understood, but you need to rule out the fact that the code is causing the issue. If the issue persists without C# code, then your code isn't the problem and the problem lies with the ASP.NET markup. I do think though, that you don't need the Nodes section in the markup if you're adding nodes using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a asp tree view in sharepoint you need to create a datasource for it. That's why you are getting the _Data error. I took a look on google for a good guide for you here:

**[How to use a asp tree view with SharePoint](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32389/How-to-Use-TreeView-in-Current-Navigation-in-Share)**

Comment: but this is just a demo my true intention is to bind it from SPList and that also i've tried but the result was same

Comment: Well the error is that you haven't set your data source for the tree. Basically the points in step 2 are missing from your code, without the datasource it won't work I'm afraid.

Comment: but in farm solution it is working perfectly without data source....do i compulsory have to give DataSourceId in design view????....and please note that i m using it in sandbox solution

Comment: System.Web.UI is fine, in SharePoint online, so it should be fully supported. I'm just wondering could you paste a more complete version of your code, I feel there is something I am not seeing so I probably misunderstanding the situation.

Comment: i have add my new code in this question. So please have a look at it....